# How to disable YouTube context menu in react player (reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, contextmenu, react-player

I've Implemented the react player within a react js site it works fine I can embed video from Vimeo, youtube, and lots of other platforms. Now I need to hide or disable the context menu of youtube videos inside the react player. I made a change as below,

```
<ReactPlayer
              url={videoLink}
              controls={true}
              pip={true}
              className="player"
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              playing={true}
              controls={true}
              onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
              config={{
                youtube: {
                  playerVars: {
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    fs: 0,
                  },
                },
              }}
            />
```

after adding **onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}** I was able to disable the context menu
but I can still access the youtube context menu. so how I can disable the youtube context menu within react player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this.

- YouTube uses its own JavaScript to overwrite the right click menu.
- You will get SecurityError if you try to access the frame because the `_top` place is different from `youtube.com`.
- Try using `contentWindow` to disable the JavaScript context menu. In a perfect world, this should work.

```js
var youtube = document.getElementById('yourYoutubeFrame');
youtube = youtube.contentWindow;
youtube.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Blocked!");
}
```

- Try it out, you will recieve a message that the browser `blocked a frame with origin yoursite.com from accessing a frame with origin youtube-nocookie.com`.

Comment: Is there any other way to hide the context menu using css or js?

Comment: `No. You cannot access cross-site domains. Your site cannot access youtube.com.`

Comment: I'm using react-player and I want to use this solution. but in any reload 'yourYoutubeFrame' get new id :(

Comment: @Osada: Actually, you might be able to do it by positioning a div over it: https://jsfiddle.net/A_random_programmer/yvb0f3w9/5/